# National income intermediate consumption

Tags: national-income

My economics teacher said that amount paid by a business firm to a lawyer for hiring his services is intermediate consumption hence it should not be included but my question is why it is intermediate consumption ?

Answer (score 1):

Because by definition it is. [Intermediate consumption](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Glossary:Intermediate_consumption):

> Intermediate consumption is a national accounts concept which measures the value of the goods and services consumed as inputs by a process of production

firms hire lawyers as part of their business so it is part of the production.